# Laravel foreach not closing

Tags: laravel

I have a simple foreach in blade template :

```
@foreach ($collection as $item)
  <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->nom}}</option>
@endforeach
```

But if i die and dump like so OUT OF THE LOOP :

```
@dd($item)
```

It returns me the last model of the loop.
But i need it to be undefined and really don't understand how it is possible.

I don't get it...

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance !
Julien

Comment: Check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: It is the default behavior of PHP foreach. You can reset the variable using `unset($item);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset($item);
```

It was the good way to go.
Thank you